# Calculating between dates fields from a previous record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
  Patient Code   Unique Visit Code    AdmitDate     Discharge Date
  91260          10146440             7/20/2013     9/16/2013
  91260          10217043             9/21/2013     11/2/2013
```

This is a single patient with 2 different visits to the physician, I need to take the Discharge date of the earliest visit (9/16/2013) and the AdmitDate of the most recent visit (9/21/2013) and determine if it's within a 30 day period.  How do I accomplish this in SQL 2008

Comment: 1st Record - Static Patient Code = 91260 Unique Visit Code 10146440 Discharge Date = 9/16/2013   2nd Record Static Patient Code = 91260, Unique Visit Code 10217043 Admit Date = 9/21/2013. Need to determine if the Admit Date < 30 days from the Discharge Date

Comment: Hi Nizam, It doesn't work, if I only have a single visit for a patient, example patient code 123 unique visit 456 admit date 7/1/2014 discharge date 7/5/2014 it makes it a 1.  I'm only interested in patients who have two visits and their first visit has a minimum discharge date of 7/5/2014 and their 2nd visit has an admit date of 7/15/2014, this would be considered a 1 because they came back within 30 days of their last visit.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT PATIENT_CODE, 
     CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(DISCHARGE_DATE), MAX(ADMIT_DATE)) < 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY PATIENT_CODE
```

The code

```
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(DISCHARGE_DATE), MAX(ADMIT_DATE)) < 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

will be 1 for those visits which occurs in period less than 30 days.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ff050/2)